# How can I loop through this associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I have a following array which is an output from mysqli_fetch_object.
I want to loop through it via foreach but I am not sure how to do it.. Sorry I am newbie..

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Furious1"
    ["count_vps"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["maxvps"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Furious4"
    ["count_vps"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["maxvps"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Furious3"
    ["count_vps"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["maxvps"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
```

This is an output of array using print_r() function.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `foreach ($array as $item)`

Comment: That was simple.. Oh my, many thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $arr)
{
     $arr->name;
     $arr->count_vps;
     $arr->maxvps;
}
```

Comment: Yes, figured it out. Thanks for response :)